# D3 data structure? (that facilitates lookups, data manipulation and selections)

Tags: javascript, data-structures, d3.js

I am exploring data structures and libraries that can be helpful in developing a larger D3 application.

I am getting data from multiple csv files and want to store the data in javascript in a consistent manner (arrays/objects/other) so that I can **simplify lookups, data manipulation and use with D3 selections**.

I am currently considering storing the data with keys like this:

```
var people = {
        A : { id: 'A', name: 'Joe'},
        B : { id: 'B', name: 'Sam'},
        C : { id: 'C', name: 'Eve'}
    };
```

This way I would be able to do quick lookups as well as easily flatten the structure using for example d3.values().

**Are there better alternatives?

What are the pros and cons of this approach?**

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your application what kind of data structure you need, so there's no general answer to this question. It does look as if what you have is well-suited for the most common operations you would want to do in D3 though, namely

- passing data to `.data()` to append/update elements -- for this you need an array, but your data structure can be converted into that easily using e.g. `d3.entries()`,
- cross-referencing data from other objects -- this would usually be done through lookups, for which your data structure is also suitable as it indexes by ID.

Comment: Thanks, I realize it is a bit vague. All clues are however welcome! Also custom data structure implementations :) ps. Why would you use d3.entries and not d3.values?

Comment: In your case, `d3.values()` would be sufficient I guess as you have the ID in both keys and values.